# Get days based on integer week and year in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate, posixct

I have many strings like `"200046"`. The first four digits are the year, and the last two is the number of the week per year. I'm trying to find the 7 days of the week for that week. I tried something like

```
date = as.Date(str, "%Y%M")
```

but it returns `"2000-01-29"` which is not the 46th week of 2000. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add day of the week to `str`.

```
str <- '200046'
as.Date(paste0(str, 1), "%Y%U%u")
#[1] "2000-11-13"
```

This is 1st day (Monday) of 46th week of 2000.

Now to get all days of the week you can do :

```
as.Date(paste0(str, 1), "%Y%U%u") + 0:6
#[1] "2000-11-13" "2000-11-14" "2000-11-15" "2000-11-16" "2000-11-17" "2000-11-18" "2000-11-19"
```